# Why aren't these strings equal

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ out of curiosity - my current task is to check if a string is a palindrome. What should be happening is the string is reversed, and I use the Equal To (==) operator to compare the original and reversed string. But for some reason, they're all returning as false, and I can't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string reverse_string(string text) {
  int string_size = text.size();
  string reversed = "";
  while (string_size >= 0) {
    reversed += text[string_size];
    string_size--;
  };
  return reversed;
}

bool is_palindrome(string text) {
  if (reverse_string(text) == text) {
    return true;
  };
  return false;
}

int main() {
  cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
  cout << is_palindrome("ada") << "\n";
  cout << is_palindrome("lovelace") << "\n";
}
```

For the record, I'm doing this via Codeacademy - It's returning false (0) for both the browser CMD prompt, as well as local.

Something I'm noticing that if I try to log the comparison `(reversed_string == text)`, I'm getting a single random integer. I'm not sure why that's happening; shouldn't it just be returning 0 or 1?

Comment: Aside: instead of `if (x) return true; return false;` you’d normally write `return x;`. It’s identical code but it’s shorter and more readable since it omits unnecessary code.

Comment: @evg [not since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)

Comment: `std::string`, like may other containers has a convenient `rbegin()` and `rend()` methods: reverse begin and reverse end. That makes reversing the whole string easy: `return std::string{text.rbegin(), text.rend()};`

Comment: @Caleth Indeed!

Comment: side note: `bool isPalindome(string s) { return std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size() / 2, s.rbegin()); };`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ indexing is zero-based. Thus `string_size`, while initially being the length of the string, is *one past the end of the string*.

So in your loop’s first iteration you are indexing past the string, leading to the zero termination character (`'\0'`) being returned. To fix this it’s enough to decrement the index just *before* performing the indexing operation.

Comment: @Caleth Oh that’s news to me. I know that C++11 guarantees zero termination and contiguity but not that the access was valid.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The tricky part is whether it's UB to overwrite `\0` with another `\0`.

Comment: @Caleth is right, if you want to be safe use `.at()` function.

Comment: This turned out to be the right answer, I was returning an 'invisible' char (terminating zero) when building the string. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

The other answers explain how you've failed to reverse your string; but you don't need to copy it: `std::string` has a reverse view built in:

```cpp
    bool is_palindrome(const std::string & text) {
      return std::equal(text.begin(), text.end(), text.rbegin());
    }
```

Or, if you want a string that is the reversed, you can construct it from the pair of iterators:

```cpp
    std::string reversed(const std::string & text) {
        return { text.rbegin(), text.rend() };
    }
```

Comment: And even if you _do_ need to copy it, `std::copy(text.rbegin(), text.rend(), std::back_inserter(reversed))` is easier to get right

Comment: @Useless or `std::string::string()`, indeed

Comment: Good point, I'm being excessively general again

Comment: Such a simple solution (but a good one). Moral of the story: Use the STL!

Comment: This is a good solution if I were looking to refactor; very straight-forward.

Answer (score 6):

The index of the last character in a string is that string's size (or length) *minus one* (because array and other container indexes in C++ are **zero-based**). So, in your `reverse_string` function you need to decrement the index *before* copying it. You can do this conveniently with the pre-decrement `--x` operator, as shown below:

```cpp
string reverse_string(string text)
{
    size_t string_size = text.size(); // Best to use size_t type.
    string reversed = "";
    while (string_size > 0) {
        reversed += text[--string_size]; // Decrement index BEFORE copying
    } // No need for a semicolon here!
    return reversed;
}
```

Note also the other minor changes I have made to your code.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
int string_size = text.size(); // equals 

...
while (string_size >= 0) {
   ....
}
```

if you pass "Hello" to your `reverse_string()` function you `string_size` would be 5. Your loop would go in for `5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0`. You have two solutions, decrement `string_size` or do `while (string_size > 0) {` instead of `>= 0`. Later one would also need adjustment here `reversed += text[string_size];` should be `reversed += text[string_size - 1];`

Answer (score 1):

your string reverse function is incorrect

```
string reverse_string(string text) {
  int string_size = text.size();
  string reversed = "";
  while (string_size > 0) {
    reversed += text[string_size-1];
    string_size--;
  };
  return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You see, when you are using strings in c++, it will create an array of chars to store that string in the memory. It puts a special character in the last house of that array as a flag that shows the end of that string.
Your problem is in the 'reverse_string' function. You are adding that flag to your reverse string. Thus those two strings will not be equal.

Just need to set your while loop on step forward.

```cpp
string reverse_string(string text) {
  int string_size = text.size()-1; // The change
  string reversed = "";
  while (string_size >= 0) {
    reversed += text[string_size];
    string_size--;
  };
  return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    string reverse_string(string text) {
      int string_size = text.size() - 1; //changes to be made
      string reversed = "";
      while (string_size >= 0) {
        reversed += text[string_size];
        string_size--;
      }
     return reversed;
   }
```

indexing in C/C++ starts from (0) to (length - 1). so, if we use just `text.size()` it will count whole length, but we need index here. which will be `text.size() - 1`.
Now, it is working as expected.
You can try some more examples inside it like `racecar`, `rotator`, `refer`, etc.